# I am trying to get a "+" icon to turn into a "-" icon based on a Bootstrap toggle

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, toggle

I have a few lines of text that when clicked on, there will be more text that drops down below.  I have a couple Bootstrap icons I am using, and am trying to have the "+" icon displayed when the toggle is collapsed and the "-" icon displayed when open.  I am also using Bootstrap for the toggle.  I am thinking maybe have one set as display: none while the other one is visible but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" id="question1">
<!-- Plus Icon SVG -->
                <svg class="bi bi-plus-circle" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3.5V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                  </svg>
   
<!-- Minus Icon SVG -->  
                <svg class="bi bi-dash-circle" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h8a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
                  </svg>
                  Line of text.
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body answer">
                More text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       
       
             <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" id="question2">

                <svg class="bi bi-plus-circle" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v4a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5H4a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3.5V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                  </svg>Line of text.
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body answer">
                More text
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Again, why are you using `panel` with Bootstrap 4? Are you using 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: @Zim I'm not super familiar with Bootstrap and this was a template I found to get the setup I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, well there is a considerable difference between 3.x and 4.x, and there is no panel class in 4.x. Decide which one you're using.

Comment: @Zim Alright thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can make add an event listener and use attributes to make this effect

```
 plus= document.getElementsByClassName('bi-plus-circle')[0]
minus= document.getElementsByClassName('bi-dash-circle')[0]

plus.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        plus.setAttribute('display','none')
        minus.setAttribute('display','')         
})

minus.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        plus.setAttribute('display','')
        minus.setAttribute('display','none')
          toggle=true            
})
```